# How to manage list version history in WSS 2.0

Tags: sharepoint

I know that WSS 2.0 is obsolete, but it is still being used, and in my case, I still need to work on it.  Is there any way to enable version history for a custom list in WSS 2.0? I can't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSS 2.0, the only functionality for version history applied to documents. In WSS 3.0, MS extended this to cover other types of lists (including custom lists).

I'm rusty on what can be done with this version, but you may be able to develop your own solution using event handlers in WSS 2.0. However this functionality was quite limited back in that version as well.

As WSS is free, why don't you research and consider upgrading to WSS 3.0? This will solve these issues and give you a lot more functionality.

Comment: thanks. the wss2.0 is tied with project server 2003, could it be upgraded without breaking the project server?

Comment: No - you would need to upgrade to Project Server 2007 as well. I would strongly recommend a good Microsoft partner to help with this (if you don't have one already). If you're in the UK or Australia I can make recommendations.